# How to present uiview from tabbar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on a `TabBarController` base application and my `TabBarController` has 5 tabs.

When a user clicks on the third tab I want to present a `UIView` with dimensions of 280*100 and the background shows the selected `ViewController`.

Comment: This is not possible with a `UITabBarController` because it can only present view controllers. You need to implement you own TabBarController.

Comment: Can you explain how to implement own TabBarController

Comment: I am quite confident that you know how to use the search on this page...

Comment: do you mean to show a view 280x100 on top on the third tab ViewController own view?

Comment: Are you trying to present a view controller when the user taps the center tab rather than show the tab?  This can be done with a `UITabViewController` using a dummy view controller and `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`

Answer (score 0):

Just have the 3rd tab reference a 3rd UIViewController that has a UIView with the dimensions you specified. If you are concerned about the nav info, etc. showing in the UIViewContoller, then you can suppress all of that.

[image]

If you want to use the tab bar to change the UI appearance of the same UIViewController (e.g. tab1 shows a UIView, tab2 shows a button, etc. all within the same VC) then you are using the wrong control.

See this [UITabBarController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the role of UITabBarController